# Protractor isSelected giving false reading after re-enabling checkboxes

Tags: angularjs, selenium, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I have a list of checkboxes and at the top a `all` checkbox. When toggling the all checkbox, all checkboxes will get deselected or selected.

By default/initially, `all` checkbox is enabled with all checkboxes checked. So, I will deselect the all checkbox and all the checkboxes will uncheck.  This passes no with no issues in protractor:

```
  it('all checkbox is deselected', function() {
    modelsAllCheckbox.click();
    expect(modelsAllCheckbox.isSelected()).to.eventually.be.false;
  });

  it('all models should be deselected', function() {
    ppvPercentages.modelChoices().then(function(modelChoices) {
      modelChoices.forEach(function(modelChoice) {
        expect(modelChoice.isSelected()).to.eventually.be.false;
      });
    });
  });

  this.modelChoices = function(rowNumber) {
    return element.all(by.repeater('model in vehicleCheckboxes.models'));
  }
```

Then I re-enable the `all` checkbox. I visually can see, in the browser, the all checkbox being checked in all the checkboxes successfully being checked/selected. Hoewever, in the test to assert they are all selected fails:

```
  it('all button is re-enabled', function() {
    modelsAllCheckbox.click();
    expect(modelsAllCheckbox.isSelected()).to.eventually.be.true;
    // give time for all models to set
    browser.sleep(3000)
  });

  it('all models are selected', function() {
    ppvPercentages.modelChoices().then(function(modelChoices) {
      modelChoices.forEach(function(modelChoice) {
        expect(modelChoice.isSelected()).to.eventually.be.true;
      });
    });
  })
```

---

```
<div class="overflow-container">

  <!-- all checkbox -->
  <input type="checkbox"
    ng-model="vehicleAllCheckbox.models"
    ng-change="toggleAllModels(vehicleAllCheckbox, vehicleCheckboxes.models, vehicleCheckboxes.year)">All

  <div ng-repeat="model in vehicleCheckboxes.models | orderBy: 'description' track by model.description">
    <!-- the rest of the checkboxes -->
    <input type="checkbox"
      ng-change="modelCheckboxToggle()"
      ng-model="model.checked" >
    {{model.description}}
  </div>
</div>
```

I see all the checkboxes are checked in the browser viusally. Why is `modelChoice.isSelected()` giving false instead of true up re-enabling the all checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you are locating the checkboxes. Currently, you are targeting the parent `div` elements since you are using the `by.repeater()` locator:

```
<div ng-repeat="model in vehicleCheckboxes.models | orderBy: 'description' track by model.description">
```

Instead, point `modelChoices` to `input` elements (your checkboxes):

```
this.modelChoices = function(rowNumber) {
  return element.all(by.repeater('model in vehicleCheckboxes.models')).all(by.model('model.checked'));
}
```

---

As a side note, I think you can improve the way you are expecting the checkboxes to be selected, by either using [`.each()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each):

```
ppvPercentages.modelChoices().each(function (modelChoice) {
    expect(modelChoice.isSelected()).to.eventually.be.true;
});
```

Or, by using [`.reduce()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.reduce):

```
var allSelected = ppvPercentages.modelChoices().reduce(function (acc, modelChoice) {
    return modelChoice.isSelected().then(function (isSelected) {
        return acc && isSelected;
    });
}, true);
expect(allSelected).to.eventually.be.true;
```

Or, there are other ways as well.